# Ng ZORRO Pagination change 'page' word in UI when using nzShowSizeChanger

Tags: angular, pagination, ng-zorro-antd

When using NG-ZORRO Pagination, you can use `[nzShowSizeChanger]="true"` to show page size. As the result, the user can change the page size in a dropdown list.

You can customize the page-size list like `[nzPageSizeOptions] ="[20,50,100]"` but you can not customize the word "page" in "**page** / 20".

Is there a standard way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I should use NZ Zorro [Internationalization](https://ng.ant.design/docs/i18n/en), then I should do some changes in my module :

```
const customLanguagePack = {
  fa_IR,
}

customLanguagePack.fa_IR.Pagination.items_per_page = "my ouwn text";

@NgModule({
  providers   : [
    { provide: NZ_I18N, useValue: customLanguagePack }
  ]
})
export class PostsModule { }
```

And then in my component, I could use service to change the language:

```
  constructor(private i18n: NzI18nService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.i18n.setLocale(fa_IR);
  }
```